# Error when converting the dfm to data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I try to run this commands:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(quanteda)
 df <- data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("I am loving it"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 myDfm <- df$text %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
     tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"))) %>%
     dfm()


out <- convert(myDfm, to = "data.frame")
pivot_longer(out, cols = !contains("document"), names_to = "features", values_to = "count")  %>% 
    mutate(id = as.integer(gsub("[a-z]", "", document))) %>% 
    inner_join(df) %>% # joins on id
    select(id, features) # select only the id and features column
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error: `!contains("document")` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Try changing `cols = !contains("document")` to `cols == !contains("document")`

Comment: @Matt I tried it and receive this error: `Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'cols' not found
`

Comment: You can try to create a vector of column names that contain "document", and then change your code to `cols = document_vector`. It's hard to help you because you haven't provided any sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `-contains("document")` instead of `!contains("document")` so that it doesn't return a logical vector. So for your case:

```
pivot_longer(out, cols = -contains("document"), names_to = "features", values_to = "count")  %>% 
    mutate(id = as.integer(gsub("[a-z]", "", document))) %>% 
    inner_join(df) %>% # joins on id
    select(id, features) # select only the id and features column
```

Note that it depends on package versions, at `tidyselect 1.1.0` and `dplyr 1.0.0` it runs even with the exclamation mark.